Linking/consolidating cases
We are a trade union. Most of our cases involve representing one worker against one employer. However, sometimes, we get group issues involving as many as 20 or 30 workers. Does anyone have suggestions on the most effective way of collectively dealing with group cases?

We have worked with a union that needed this. They have 3 types of Cases

Individual
Collective
Enterprise Agreement

For Collective ones, the business is registered as the 'client' and the members involved are related to the Case via a separate Relationship. So there is just one Case that encompasses all the affected workers.

Thanks for the suggestions. I suspected your suggestion might be the way to go, but the fact that others have used this approach successfully is comforting.

Sweet. Ours was using a Drupal platform so most of the UI was via webforms and views. am sure native civi can handle it better now but we needed lots of dashboards to help the case managers and their managers all keep really good tabs on what the current state of play was. also in inbound emails as Activities to ensure email threads with clients were kept in the case.

https://civicrm.org/extensions/documents was also really important part of their toolkit which we had to extend to ensure it all played nicely with webforms but would have contributed code back to the maintainers

Sometimes the answer to these types of questions is determined by "what reports do you need", but here's some ideas:

Create a separate case for each employee, and use the "link cases" feature to link them together. This might be useful for orgs that have extra privacy rules where you need to keep the information separate, or makes it easier if they ask for their file then you can give it to them without weeding stuff out.

Create a contact subtype for orgs called something like "group claim". Make org contacts with that subtype representing each group. Give the relevant employees an employee relationship (or some other relationship) to that org. Then make the case client be that org.

Pick someone as the "spokesperson" for the group, and make them the case client. Give the other people roles on the case.



Thanks for the suggestion. I think suggestion 2. might be a favourite to explore.
